# Creating the Iphone MapKit showUserLocation Ring Annimation

Tags: ios, iphone, animation, mapkit, core-location

Anyone know how of an approach to re-create the animation that mapkit uses on the showUserLocation ?  Would you do it with a series of images or a single image that is then expanded and faded out?

Comment: Are you planning to use this same animation, but outside of the mapkit context?  Apple might not like that...

Answer (score 1):

I just looked at it, and it looks a bit too complex to do with a single image and some sort of UIView animation.  I'd just bite the bullet and use a set of images for it -- the total footprint can't be very much.

It's a beautiful animation though, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how Apple does it exactly but I know they're using 3 differently sized images for their halo animation. Probably because scaling the largest image to a small size would result in artifacts.